# Updating WebGLTexture by texSubImage2D looses data?

Tags: canvas, webgl

As soon as I update a WebGLTexture using texSubImage2D with a HtmlCanvasElement, all thin lines disappear. Rendering the related canvas into another canvas works fine even with image smoothing enabled though.

Creating a canvas:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ww, hh);
ctx.lineWidth = 0.25;
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(51,51,51,0.75)";
ctx.beginPath();
  for (let xx = 0; xx < ww; xx += 8) {
  ctx.moveTo(xx, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(xx, hh);
};
for (let yy = 0; yy < hh; yy += 8) {
  ctx.moveTo(0, yy);
  ctx.lineTo(ww, yy);
};
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
```

Now passing it into a WebGLTexture:

```
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, my_texture);
gl.texSubImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, my_canvas);
```

Note that I'm using a line width of 0.25px and a strokeStyle rgba color with alpha 0.75 to draw a very thin grid onto my canvas;

Comment: How did you create the texture in the first place? Are you using mips?

Comment: ctx.lineWidth = 0.25;ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(51,51,51,0.75)" ctx.strokeRect(20, 20, 80, 100); this is not visible on white background try it on https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_linewidth